# Set stroke width and color of a shape in java

Tags: java, android, stroke

I am creating an app that you can use to design custom buttons easily by setting all the settings in the app and immediatly being able to see a preview. For the button, I use a shape and I have set that shape as the background. In the shape I have the normal `android:width=""` and `android:color=""` codes but I need to be able to change these in the app itself. I already have this for other aspects such as the corners using a drawable (see my question about that (solved) [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24861759/changin-corner-radius-of-a-shape-in-java)) I already tried things like `drawable.setStroke()` but this doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parsing the right color using Color.parseColor("#000000") helped me. I don't know why it didn't work when I provided the color myself but atleast I fixed it.

Answer (score -1):

This might help you..

```
<!-- view border color and width -->
<stroke
    android:width="3dp"
    android:color="@android:color/black" >
</stroke>

<corners android:radius="3dp" />

<solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
```

Comment: @JoppeD Use this...
    int strokeWidth = 5; // 3dp
    int roundRadius = 15; // 8dp
    int strokeColor = Color.parseColor("#2E3135");
    int fillColor = Color.parseColor("#DFDFE0");

    GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable();
    gd.setColor(fillColor);
    gd.setCornerRadius(roundRadius);
    gd.setStroke(strokeWidth, strokeColor);